# php number of sql queries differ per page

Tags: php, sql

I am not sure if this is the correct site to post it but we'll see.

So i am building an app where users subscribe to others and each user has 2 pages for Subscribers and Subscriptions to check his data.

I then added a Subscribe/Unsubscribe button in the Subscriptions page(must be logged in and be the owner of the subscriptions) next to each user that has subscribed to a user but this has to check to see if the logged in user has subscribed or not to show the proper button.

If for example i show 20 per page items i have to do 20 more SQL queries... with some other data that i require for the page to render it can go to 50 sql queries... is this normal or im using way to many Queries?

**EDIT :**

This is the function that i call to check if i have subscribed to any of my subscriptions to show the proper button

```
public function hasSubscribedTo($user_id){
    $this->db->where('uid', $this->session->userdata['uid']);
    $this->db->where('suid', $user_id);
    $sql = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix('subscribers'));
    return $sql->num_rows();
}
```

Comment: Show examples of your queries.  My guess is that you're running more queries than is necessary, but it totally depends on the queries you are running

Comment: i updated the post. The other queries are still required for different things like get total subs,user data, user profile data etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is normal. But you can always have one query and then cache the data that expires in X number of seconds. and then read the cache instead. but with pagination or real time checking this stuff is normal.

You may also like to read about [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php).

Memcache module provides handy procedural and object oriented interface to memcached, highly effective caching daemon, which was especially designed to decrease database load in dynamic web applications.